# LookupError: App 'promotions' doesn't have a 'KeywordPromotion' model when upgrading to django oscar 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I have a django oscar shop that I'm attempting to upgrade to Oscar 1.6.  My shop extends Oscar's promotions model (although at this stage, does little with it).

It works fine if I remove the promotions app from the project, and it works fine in django 1.5.  However when I try to start the app in Oscar 1.6, I get the following error.

LookupError: App 'promotions' doesn't have a 'KeywordPromotion' model.

It seems that none of Oscar's promotions models are being loaded at startup.  There's a message in the release notes that says:

> The majority of the Oscar class imports now use dynamic loading,
>   instead of direct imports, for better extensibility and
>   customisability.

Does anyone know if this, or otherwise is preventing the promotions model from loading?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I didn't have a models.py in my overridden promotions app...  It just needs to contain this:

> from oscar.apps.promotions.models import *

Comment: If you had forked the promotions app via command-line (`manage.py oscar_fork_app promotions .`) then this would be there already. Glad you figured it out.